# cannot deserialize JSON return to a class using c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have this Object but can´t get success deserialize this !

```
{  
   "faturaResposta":{  
      "inT_IN_SEQREFERENCIAID":99,
      "mensagem":"SUA REQUISIÇÃO FOI CONCLUIDA COM SUCESSO. AGUARDE E REALIZE NOVAS REQUISIÇÕES PARA ACOMPANHAR O STATUS DA NOTA ENVIADA",
      "fiL_IN_CODIGO":3,
      "noT_DT_EMISSAO":"09/12/2016",
      "calC_AGN_ST_CODIGO":"08.139.771/0001-76",
      "inT_ST_STATUS":"P",
      "inT_ST_DESSTATUS":"Aguardando Criação do XML"
   }
}
```

I try using dictionary

```cs
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                Dictionary<string, object> values = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(result);
```

But this create one list inside other and i can´t get this values.

What is the mode to access this return ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two classes which represent your json

```
public class FaturaResposta
{
    public int inT_IN_SEQREFERENCIAID { get; set; }
    public string mensagem { get; set; }
    public int fiL_IN_CODIGO { get; set; }
    public string noT_DT_EMISSAO { get; set; }
    public string calC_AGN_ST_CODIGO { get; set; }
    public string inT_ST_DESSTATUS { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class RootObject
{
    public FaturaResposta faturaResposta { get; set; }
}
```

Then use `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` converter

```
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourJsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as the other answer, but using your JavaScriptSerializer

```cs
public class MyClass
    {
        public FaturaResposta FaturaResposta { get; set; }
    }

    public class FaturaResposta
    {
        public int inT_IN_SEQREFERENCIAID { get; set; }
        public string mensagem { get; set; }
        public int fiL_IN_CODIGO { get; set; }
        public string noT_DT_EMISSAO { get; set; }
        public string calC_AGN_ST_CODIGO { get; set; }
        public string inT_ST_STATUS { get; set; }
        public string inT_ST_DESSTATUS { get; set; }

    }
```

and them:

```
var deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyClass>(json);
```